# Passing CSRF token

Tags: python, post, csrf

This doesn't get past the login screen. I don't think I am passing in the CSRF token correctly. How should I do it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://app.greenhouse.io/people/new?hiring_plan_id=24047'
cookies = {'_session_id':'my_session_id'}
client = requests.session()

soup = BeautifulSoup(client.get(url, cookies=cookies).content)
csrf_metatags = soup.find_all('meta',attrs={'name':'csrf-token'})[0].get('content')
posting_data = dict(person_first_name='Morgan') ## this is what I want to post to the form
headers = dict(Referer=url, csrf_token=csrf_metatags)
r = client.post(url, data=posting_data, headers=headers)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to put the csrf token in the posting_data dict

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the code, you'll find that the form has a hidden attached value like this:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"
value="2auOlN425EcdnmmoXmd5HFCt4PkEOhq0gpjOCzxNKns=" />
```

You can catch this value with:

```
csrf_data = soup.find("input", {"name": "authenticity_token"}).get("value")
```

Now re-attach the value to the posting data, as you did with `person_first_name`:

```
posting_data = dict(person_first_name='Morgan',
                    authenticity_token=csrf_data)
```